# Customize radio button - Of the border and the selected dot in it

Tags: html, css

Can anyone suggest how I can modify a radio button to change both the color of the border and that of the dot in it upon selection (Also, is it possible to modify the size of the dot in it - I don't want a complete fill).

I don't want to see the square border - that I think the browser generates - around the radio button upon selection either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Codepen doing exactly what you're looking for.

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

body, html{
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.container{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 450px;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0; top:0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
 color: #AAAAAA;
 font-weight: normal;
}

.container ul{
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


ul li{
  color: #AAAAAA;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
}

ul li input[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

ul li:hover label{
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
 z-index: 5;
 transition: border .25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

ul li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}

ul li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
 content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
 transition: background 0.25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #0DFF92;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #0DFF92;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #0DFF92;
}

.signature {
 position: fixed;
 margin: auto;
 bottom: 0;
 top: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

.signature p{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 color: #AAAAAA;
}

.signature .much-heart{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 4px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 background: #AC1D3F;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.signature .much-heart::before, 
.signature .much-heart::after {
   display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #AC1D3F;
  top: -4px;
}

.signature .much-heart::after {
 bottom: 0;
 top: auto;
 left: -4px;
}

.signature a {
 color: #AAAAAA;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
 <h2>For dinner I would like to eat:</h2>
 
  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="f-option" name="selector">
    <label for="f-option">Pizza</label>
    
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="s-option" name="selector">
    <label for="s-option">Spaghetti</label>
    
    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="t-option" name="selector">
    <label for="t-option">Tacos</label>
    
    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="signature">
 <p>Made with <i class="much-heart"></i> by <a href="http://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez">Angela Velasquez</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no way to style a radio button directly and is up to the browser on how to display it. I'm not sure what browser you're using, but Chrome or FireFox doesn't give a border upon selection. But you can still try `input[type=radio] { outline:none }` to remove it.